# (iReport) How to locate the x axis at the bottom of the bar chart?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, bar-chart

I have created a horizontal bar chart in iReport Designer 5.1.0. 
Does anyone know how I can locate the x axis at the bottom of the bar chart by setting its properties?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean, change the location of x axis? As far as I know, you can do this with multi axis chart. If you want to do it for a bar chart, you have to use chart customizer. Here's a [link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/516616/x-axis-bar-charts-horizontal-orientation) on how to achieve the same.